# Chrome Update Version 24.0.1312.52 m Messes up Word Spacing

Tags: css, google-chrome, word-spacing

Chrome was recently updated and now some of my sites with a style of word spacing is wrapping to the second line with the last word.  You can view it at the link below, with the header (H1) tag.  Is this a bug or is there a work around? This is on Windows 7 64 bit.

http://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/3008/3rd-4th-boys-basketball-tournament

Comment: Don't see any wrapping in Chrome 25.0.1364.29 on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using chrome canary(V.26 on Windows 7) and I see this effect as well. I used chrome inspector to see if it was in the css code and it seem that this code

```
in element
<div class="event-details">


 body.event .event-header .event-details {
float: left;
}
```

is causing this effect, correct me if I'm wrong :)

**EDIT**

If this is your site you can prevent it by adding this to the code `min-width: 540px;`
or just removing `float:left`

This question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598110/prevent-floated-divs-from-wrapping-to-next-line) might be similar to your problem.

Comment: This wasnt happening before and you can see it works fine in IE and Firefox.  Something happened within Chrome.

Comment: Can you accept my question as I see you have removed `float: left;` from your code

Comment: I removed the float:left for now, but it wasnt doing that before.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the width of the element is less than the width of the text so it is wrapped.  Try increasing the size of the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that have been reported, please refer to [Issue #170226](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170226) for more information. It has not been fixed as of Chromium Version 27.0.1413.0 (182441).

Before it is fixed, I suggest applying Chrome specific CSS to set `word-spacing: 0;` to elements that suffered from the problem. To do so, checkout [CSS Browser Selector](https://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector).